# I cannot install android sdk in eclipse helios after cancelling it once

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the eclipse helios sdk and clicked install sdk but then I cancelled it. After that I cant install it again!I needed to start my development in my computer as fast as possible. It says tools folder not found in /android-sdks folder. How to get rid of this problem?

Any help is Appreciated!

Thanks,
Alok

Comment: That's a statement, not a question.

Comment: For what it is worth, if you are starting out with Android. You should invest your time in Android Studio. Eclipse is not that supported by Google now.

Comment: Find that registry and delete that and restart it .

Comment: But I dont know how to! I am studying android development in eclipse. That is why.